# Can I RDP to a windows computer from a Mac running OSX

Tags: windows, macos, remote-desktop

Is there any way I can connect via remote desktop to a windows based PC from a Mac running OSX?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Microsoft provide [Remote Desktop Connection Client for Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client)

Answer (score 3):

There is also CoRD if you deal regularly with many machines or you do not like Microsoft's OS X client:

http://cord.sourceforge.net/